# Вопросы по документированию

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Хотел задать вопрос по gitbook но засомневался: будет ли он уместен? Сам вопрос в том, как описать не только методы, но и свойства оъектов в gitbook (название плагина, например). Уместен ли он на ruSO?

UPD: Как посоветовали в ответах, задал вопрос: [Описать не только методы, но и свойства объектов в gitbook](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622110/197525)

Answer (score 3):

Ну я бы задал и посмотрел. Думаю, уместны, но сомневаюсь, что кто-то ответит :)